# Android, Wrapping RecyclerView LayoutManager, RTL, Bottom-To-Top

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which uses a LayoutManager to lay-out data like this...

```
[...][5][4][3][2][1]
```

But I want to make it do this...

```
   [9][8][7][6]
[5][4][3][2][1]
```

How can I?

I have attempted to use a GridLayoutManager, but I can't make it start at the bottom-right corner and proceed left then up.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? [image]

java Code as below:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 5, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<String> datas = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
        datas.add("item:" + (i + 1));
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, datas));
}


public static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {


    private final Context context;

    private List<String> datas;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> datas) {
        this.context = context;
        this.datas = datas;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(new TextView(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(datas.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datas == null ? 0 : datas.size();
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView;
    }
}
```

}

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```